# Get index of regex match in pandas dataframe not working

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have an excel worksheet that I am reading into pandas for parsing and later analysis. It has the following format. All values are strings. They will be converted to floats/ints later but having them as strings helps with parsing.

```
column1  |  column2 | column3 |
-----------------------------
12345   |10         |20       |
txt     |25         |65       |
35615   |15         |20       |
txt     |35         |20       |
```

I need to get the index of all 5 digit, numerical values in column1. It will always be a 5 digit. I am using the following regex.

```
\b\d{5}\b
```

I am having problems getting pandas to properly match the 5 digits when using any of the built in string methods.

I have tried the following.

```
df.column1.str.contains('\b\d{5}\b', regex=True).index.list()
df.column1.str.match('\b\d{5}\b').index.list()
```

I am expecting it to return

```
[0,2]
```

Both of these return an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `r` before string, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and get index values to list:

```
i = df[df.column1.str.contains(r'\b\d{5}\b')].index.tolist()
print (i)
[0, 2]
```

Or if want parse only numeric values with length `5` change regex with `^` and `$` for start and end of string:

```
i = df[df.column1.str.contains(r'^\d{5}$')].index.tolist()
```

Comment: I missed the raw string. Does python always need a regex to be passed as a raw string for it to function correctly?